# How to override function from core service

Tags: symfony, shopware

The plan is to remove some fields from the default Shopware 6 registration form.
I've copied some twig-templates to my plugin and removed the fields like billingaddress etc ...

An error occurred in the validateRegistrationData function because the field value for billingaddress is null (sounds logic because I've deleted the field in the twig-template)

```
in vendor/shopware/platform/src/Core/Checkout/Customer/SalesChannel/RegisterRoute.php (line 259)
```

In my module I would like to override below function in the RegisterRoute.php file (service)

```
private function validateRegistrationData(...) { ... }
```

What steps are needed to properly override above function from within my custom shopware 6 plugin.

Comment: No one with experience in Symfony or Shopware who can tell me where to start?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO `validateRegistrationData` is only the first place where you have an issue, even you change the validation billing address variable is required below in `\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\SalesChannel\RegisterRoute::register()` method.

Some my suggestion to you is implementing your own RegisterRoute in your plugin and decorate or even override existing core service.

So steps:

1. implement own RegisterRoute in your plugin
2. Register it in service container with the same id as core route:

```html
<service id="Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\SalesChannel\RegisterRoute"
class="YourPlugin\Core\Checkout\Customer\SalesChannel\RegisterRoute" public="true">
            <!-- your own arguments -->
        </service>
```

4. Also I think you need to implement your own CustomerValidationFactory and AddressValidationFactory if it is needed by your business logic.

Anyway, you can also face the issue that some fields are required by Customer DAL definition, but you don't set them. So most probably you also need to change a bit CustomerDefinition, i mean override of course.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I wil try this. When I want to decorate a service it must be an interface, but I did not find a service related to this that is an interface.